# ¿Problema con el módulo Decimal con números grandes?

Tags: python, python-3.9

Necesito manejar cifras grandes de 12 dígitos en su parte entera y 21 dígitos en su parte decimal. Estoy probando con el módulo Decimal y parece ser que a partir de 10 dígitos en su parte entera, no da el resultado exacto en su parte decimal. Esto es lo que he probado:

```
import decimal

decimal.getcontext().prec = 32
print("Cifra:", decimal.Decimal(29758189406.945447970373833796405))

>> Cifra: 29758189406.9454498291015625
```

Incluso añadiendo más precisión, los resultados son diferentes. También he probado a separar la parte entera de la decimal, así:

```
print("Cifra", decimal.Decimal(29758189406) + decimal.Decimal(0.945447970373833796405))

>> Cifra: 29758189406.945447970373833879165
```

. . . y otro resultado diferente.

Trabajo con windows10-x64. ¿Hay algún otro módulo más potente para manejar este tipo de cifras, y con los decimales exactos hasta dónde yo le diga en todas las operaciones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que `29758189406.945447970373833796405` es un `float`, literal pero `float` al fin, con lo cual el número con el que inicializas el `Decimal` arrastra los problemas de este tipo de datos.

Para inicializar un `Decimal` y que respete efectivamente el valor literal que quieres asignarle, debes indicarle una cadena:

```
print("Cifra:", decimal.Decimal("29758189406.945447970373833796405"))
Cifra: 29758189406.945447970373833796405
```

Comment: Funcionó. Gracias Patricio :)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes editar la precisión del modulo, por defecto viene a 10, como tu bien dices. Pero puedes elevarlo tanto como quieras(tiene limite). En este ejemplo subo la precisión a 50.

Necesitas instalar `pip install mpmath`

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
import math

import mpmath

getcontext().prec = 50
mpmath.mp.dps = 50
num = Decimal(1) / Decimal(7)

num2 = mpmath.mpf(1) / mpmath.mpf(7)

print("   math.sqrt: {0}".format(Decimal(math.sqrt(num))))
print("decimal.sqrt: {0}".format(num.sqrt()))
print(" mpmath.sqrt: {0}".format(mpmath.sqrt(num2)))
print('actual value: 0.3779644730092272272145165362341800608157513118689212')
```

Resultado:

```
precision.py
    math.sqrt: 0.37796447300922719758631274089566431939601898193359375
 decimal.sqrt: 0.37796447300922722721451653623418006081575131186892
  mpmath.sqrt: 0.37796447300922722721451653623418006081575131186892
 actual value: 0.3779644730092272272145165362341800608157513118689212
```